# updating a field in table A only by insert operation in table B

Tags: python, mysql, django, transactions

i'm writing some sort of api for  websites who can't access to banks payment gateways directly ... basically user would create a gateway on my website and uses that gateway to connect to banks and make transactions

here is my gateway model

```
class Gateways(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , editable=False)
    key = models.UUIDField(unique=True , editable=False , default=uuid.uuid1().hex)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100 , default='')
    confirm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    money  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4 , editable=False)
```

here is my transaction model

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , editable=False)
    gate = models.ForeignKey(Gateways , editable=False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4 , editable=False)
    date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , editable=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100  , editable=False)
```

so it looks kinda like this

transaction

```
| id       | user_id | gate_id   | amount
---------------------------------------------
|       1  |  23     |    110    |  5000
```

gateway

```
| id     | user_id | key       | money
---------------------------------------------
| 110    |  23     | abcd      |  10000
```

basically i want gateway `money` field to be updated only with each transaction `amount`

i have 2 option

1 - doing it by code like after transaction is done ( pleas ignore syntax errors)

```
gate = Gateway.objects.get(id = transaction.gate_id )
gate.money = gate.money +  transaction.amount 
gate.save()
```

2 - use trigger in database

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  new_transaction
  AFTER INSERT
  ON transactions
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE  gateways SET money = money + NEW.amount WHERE id  = NEW.gate_id      ;     

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

i'm very new to django/python so it's better ask and be safe than sorry

is there a better or safer option , perhaps some sort of built-in solution in django or it's ORM ?

Comment: When creating models/tables please try to aviod names that involve the word transaction. it can be confusing! You have an asnwer that django post_save signals can do the trick. Certainly it can, but triggers happen at a lower level and exclusively in the backend so it maybe better suited for your task.

Comment: @e4c5 yeah i know i wanted to talk about  database transaction/rollbacks but i thought it would be really confusing ... thanks i 'm leaning toward triggers as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use django `post_save`
see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save

Update your models.py with the below codes

```
def update_money(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       gate = Gateway.objects.get(id = instance.gate_id )
       gate.money = gate.money +  transaction.amount 
       gate.save()        


signals.post_save.connect(update_money, sender=Transactions)
```